# SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list - what's wrong?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to debug some Javascript/jQuery, and I'm getting this error. It appears to be due to a missing parenthesis, but I try to put one all around where it's pointing in firebug, and it isn't fixing it.

Here's the code:

```
(function($) {
Drupal.behaviors.module_jvectormap = {
attach: function (context, settings) {

  $('#uscounties').vectorMap(
    onRegionClick: function(event, code) {
      $('#us-county').val(code);
    }
  );
}
}

})(jQuery);
```

What's wrong with the code here?

Here's the error:

```
SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

onRegionClick: function(event, code) {
```

Comment: Inline code should be clearer for you: `$('#uscounties').vectorMap(onRegionClick:function(…){…})`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a syntax error. You forgot to wrap your `vectorMap` settings in an object. This code should work.

```
(function($) {
Drupal.behaviors.module_jvectormap = {
attach: function (context, settings) {

  $('#uscounties').vectorMap({
    onRegionClick: function(event, code) {
      $('#us-county').val(code);
    }
  });
}
}

})(jQuery);
```

Comment: i had `}(jquery));`. stay alert, stay alive.

Answer (score 2):

You're missing the object braces:

```
$('#uscounties').vectorMap({
    onRegionClick: function(event, code) {
        $('#us-county').val(code);
    }
});
```